# What is the syntax for headers in aws_cloudfront_distribution forwarded_values (Terraform)?

Tags: caching, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

The [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution) does not show the example so it's unclear to me. How should it be properly?

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "this" {
  ...
  default_cache_behavior {
    max_ttl = 86400

    forwarded_values {
      # which option?
      headers      = ["Cache-Control max-age"]
      headers      = ["Cache-Control: max-age"]        
      headers      = ["Cache-Control-max-age"]
      headers      = ["something else?"]
      ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` has the key: `Cache-Control` and value: `max-age=86400`. You need to use only the name `Cache-Control`, without the `max-age` part.